# How To Produce Colored Map Based On Some Values

Tags: java, swing, dictionary, geotools

I have a shape file, a simple a map of countries that I need to display on screen, but each country needs to be a specific color. Say I have an `int` variable named `HKDensity = 21`, then if a value of 21 is red, the color of the Hongkong polygon should be red.

This is for a school assignment in Java Swing, any help, hints examples is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the format of your shape file? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [GeoTools Style tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/examples/stylelab.html) for details of how to display a shapefile and colour in the polygons. The tutorial only shows how to produce a single colour but you should be able to work out how to create a variable colour fill with out too much difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

```
Color colour = new Color(/*r*/ density / MAX_DENSITY, /*g*/ density / MAX_DENSITY, /*b*/ density / MAX_DENSITY);
```

or something.